# tri state treeview check / uncheck / Indeterminate parent only

Tags: c#-4.0, treeview, tri-state-logic

I am using a tri state treeview, I want to be able to check check a parent only without checking all or part of its children or giving it Indeterminate state.
I  used this function but it is not working properly

```
private void treeSysFunctions_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (!e.Node.Checked)
        {
            TreeNode parent = e.Node.Parent;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                bool hasCheckedChild = HasCheckedChild(parent);

                if (!hasCheckedChild)
                    treeSysFunctions.SetChecked(parent, Elegant.Ui.Extensions.TriStateTreeView.CheckState.Indeterminate);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working properly? What does it do currently and what do you expect it to do? Have you tried printing out the variables inside the function to debug?

Comment: I want to change the state of the parent only, but actually all the children are also get the same state Indeterminate